# Problem installing Delphi 2007 on Windows 7 64 Bit Enterprise

Tags: windows, delphi, installation, delphi-2007, windows-7-x64

I have an issue installing Delphi 2007 RAD Studio Professional onto Windows 7 64 Bit Enterprise.

Everything is fine until I enter the serial number for the installation. After I enter it and click the next button in the installation wizard I get an installation script error at line 906. OKing that error closes the installer.

I have done some Googling but have not found anything similar yet (though I have found a lot of references to people who have installed it on various versions of 64 bit windows and who have had other issues).

I have been able to install Delphi 2009 on the same machine with no problems.

I'd really like to get 2007 installed as this is currently our primary Delphi development IDE.

Comment: Not sure if this applies to older versions, but I have seen posts in the past where people indicate that Embarcadero has free support for installation issues.  Might be worth a telephone call...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had problems installing Delphi 2007 from my original DVD from CodeGear.  However, after logging into the CodeGear/Embarcadero website, I was able to download the latest DVD ISO (with all updates already applied) for Delphi 2007 and that resolved all of my installation issues.

I'd suggest trying that. Also, you will need to uninstall your broken installation if possible. Try using [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) (free) to help with getting rid of all the extra stuff left around from a broken installation.

Comment: ... I'm not sure the 2007 installer actually installed anything as it did not get past the page in the wizard that asks for the serial number.

Comment: I was able to find a Delphi 2007 installer that had the December 2007 update. This installed OK, though the help did not install (displaying message "Error", then exiting). It runs OK, and I have also run the updater, which Identifies a May help update which when installed presents the same error message, which is a annoying!

Answer (score 1):

You mention you previously installed Delphi 2009 on the same machine. Could it be you are running into [this](http://support.codegear.com/article/36724) issue? I quote:

> Symptom: Attempting to install Delphi
>   2007 or C++Builder 2007 results in
>   Install Script Error 1580.
>
> Cause: This problem occurs when the installer is run from a directory
>   that contains a slip file for a
>   different product than the one being
>   installed.
>
> Solution: Save the installer (i.e. setup.exe) to an empty directory
>   before running it. For example:
>   c:\temp\delphi2007.

Comment: I tried installing 2009 after attempting to install 2007. I have both installed on the machine being replaced, so I know they coexist peacefully!

Comment: Yes, once installed they do coexist peacefully, but their installers and .slip files do _not_. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to install into the default folder (%PROGRAMFILES%\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0), you could be having trouble with permissions. Are you running the installer as an Administrator?

You should try re-running the installation as Administrator, and install to somewhere other than %PROGRAMFILES%. I have D2007, D2009, and D2010 all running on Win7 64 Home Premium in a folder called E:\Delphi, to which I can safely give read/write access to everyone. (Later versions of Delphi are sensitive to access rights and UAC under Vista and Win7, but D7 and 2007 not so much; both of those try to write information to the ($BDS) folders, which is verboten under Vista and Win7).

Comment: I'm already running as a local administrator. I have also configured install.exe to run as administrator. I also get the Win7 UAC dialog asking to allow the installer to make changes to the computer (which I confirm). Using a different folder would be fine if the installer made it past the serial number screen, which it does not.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess I'd agree this should be a case for CG/EMBT installation support. They should be able to tell you where the installation log is written (if there is one) that might indicate what the problem is, or how to run the installation with a switch that would cause the log to be written. Sorry I couldn't help.