# Delphi 2007 Help System Install "Error"

Tags: delphi, installation, delphi-2007

Did you ever solve the following problem? I am experiencing it. I'm running Windows 7 x64.

"I was able to find a Delphi 2007 installer that had the December 2007 update. This installed OK, though the help did not install (displaying message "Error", then exiting). It runs OK, and I have also run the updater, which Identifies a May help update which when installed presents the same error message, which is a annoying! – Raymond Wilson Jan 28 at 23:08"

Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: Hi Jared, why did you post your question here? It is evidently addressed to Ray!..

Comment: because Ray asked the question here, but it was never answered. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148794/problem-installing-delphi-2007-on-windows-7-64-bit-enterprise

Answer (score 0):

I use the following.

Download an install the Delphi XE 30-days trial.
Then install the help from Delphi XE.

Even though I don't use the new Delphi XE i still use the new help as a reference. It has lots of newly documented stuff.

Comment: Thanks, i have got Help for other versions of Delphi including 2009, 2010, XE, but i was hoping to be able to use the help files specifically from Delphi 2007. Anyone else have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

May be you'll find [this IDE](http://code.google.com/p/theunknownones/wiki/CustomHelp) expert helpful ([video demo](http://www.vimeo.com/7200411)).

You may have any numbers of help systems in your IDE (incl. D7 or docwiki.embarcadero.com).

Comment: Thanks Alexander. That looks like a very cool help tool for all IDEs. I will try it out.